# Runtime Error '91 when saving email attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

We use a shared Outlook email box and we need to save some of the attachments from that email.

I need the macro to:

- Allow user to select multiple emails and save all the attachments in the selection
- Allow the user to select what folder to save the attachments in (it will be different every time)
- Add the `ReceivedTime` to the file name as we get some email attachments with the same name but they are always received on different days
- Not alter the original email (don't delete the attachment or add a note to the email)

I have combined different lines from macros I found.

On both lines with "***" I get

> "Runtime error 91: "object variable or With block variable not set"

I remove the `dateFormat` and `SaveAs` and still get the runtime error on the `SaveAs` line.

```vb
Sub saveAttachment()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim objSel As Outlook.Selection
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String

    dateFormat = Format(objMsg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")  '***

    Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
    Set xlObj = New Excel.Application
    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With xlObj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        ElseIf .Show = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Failed to select folder to save attachements to"
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    xlObj.Quit
    Set xlObj = Nothing
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each objMsg In objSelection
        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        If lngCount > 0 Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile sFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName & dateFormat '***
        Else
            MsgBox "No attachements selected"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

We are utilizing Office365.

Comment: Hello,

    ***dateFormat = Format(objMsg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")***

You are trying to access objMsg before it is assigned. If you move this code inside the loop below, it should work.

    ***objAtt.SaveAsFile sFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName & dateFormat***

Same kind of problem: objAtt is never assigned. You would first have to loop on objAttachments and take action of each attachment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to place the `Format` method inside the loop where the mail item is accessible and instantiated. Then you need to make sure the file path is valid and no forbidden symbols are used in the file name.

```
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
For Each objMsg In objSelection
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    If lngCount > 0 Then
      dateFormat = Format(objMsg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
      objAtt.SaveAsFile sFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName & dateFormat
    Else
      MsgBox "No attachements selected"
    End If
Next
```

You may find the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article helpful.

Comment: Now I get a run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.[objAtt.SaveAsFile sFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName & dateFormat]

Answer (score 0):

Return an object property after you have the object.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Sub saveAttachment()

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objAtts As Attachments
    Dim objAtt As Attachment
    Dim objSel As Selection
    
    Dim lngCount As Long
    
    Dim sFolder As String
    
    Dim dateFormat As String
    
    Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
    Set xlObj = New Excel.Application
    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With xlObj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        ElseIf .Show = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Failed to select folder to save attachements to"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    xlObj.Quit
    Set xlObj = Nothing
    
    ' .Selection allows more than one item
    Set objSel = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
    For Each objItem In objSel
        
        ' Mailitems only
        If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
        
            dateFormat = Format(objItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            Set objAtts = objItem.Attachments
            
            lngCount = objAtts.Count
            If lngCount > 0 Then
                For Each objAtt In objAtts
                    Debug.Print sFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName
                    objAtt.SaveAsFile sFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "No attachments in " & objItem.Subject
            End If
            
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```